# ORA-02270 No hay ninguna clave única o primaria correspondiente para esta lista de columnas

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Soy bastante nuevo en Oracle/SQL y estaba intentando crear una tabla "Montania" que "herede" los atributos de la tabla "AccidenteGeografico" (Hago esto porque en el modelo entidad-relación hay una relación jerárquica entre ambas entidades).

La tabla AccidenteGeográfico se ha creado pero en Montania me aparece este error.

```
create table AccidenteGeografico(
    nombreAccGeo varchar2(50),
    posVertical number(7),
    posHorizontal number(7),

    constraint pk_AccidenteGeografico primary key (nombreAccGeo)
);

create table Montania(
    IdMont number(4),
    altura number(7),
    nombreAccGeo varchar2(50),
    posVertical number(7),
    posHorizontal number(7),

    constraint pk_Montania primary key (IdMont),
    constraint fk_nombreAccGeo foreign key (nombreAccGeo) references AccidenteGeografico(nombreAccGeo),
    constraint fk_posVertical foreign key (posVertical) references AccidenteGeografico(posVertical),
    constraint fk_posHorizontal foreign key (posHorizontal) references AccidenteGeografico(posHorizontal)
);
```

Como ya dije antes soy nuevo en SQL y sólo sé las instrucciones básicas, así que no estoy muy seguro de si lo estoy haciendo bien.

Comment: Acabo de ejecutar lo que tienes tú, y no me ha salido ningún error. Qué error te sale?

Comment: El que puse en el título

Comment: Error se debe a q claves foraneas `fk_posVertical` y `fk_posHorizontal` q intenta definir en tabla `Montania` refieren columnas q en tabla `AccidenteGeografico` no estan definidas como `PRIMARY KEY` ni `UNIQUE`. Debería definir claves `UNIQUE` para las columnas `posVertical` y `posHorizontal` en `AccidenteGeografico` si desea crear esas foráneas en `Montania`; pero sospecho que no es consistente con data q desea almacenar en `AccidenteGeografico` xq mas de un accidente geográfico pueden compartir coordenada vertical u horizontal. Creo q esas foráneas sobran, ps se obtienen ya al cruzar tablas